# Background execution not allowed receiving intent action package added - Packageinstalledreceiver

Tags: android, kotlin, packageinstaller

I developing an app updater (Kotlin) for my own app with **PackageInstaller** (*android.content.pm.PackageInstaller*) and **without the Google Play**. All of my code is in the one app and when the installation is done, the app is closed, but I don't get any success message by **PackageInstaller**.
Checking the Logcat, I found this **warning**:

> *Background execution not allowed: receiving intent { act=android.intent.action.package_added dat="MY PACKAGE" flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.packageinstalledreceiver*

The **PackageInstalledReceiver** is the responsible to show the success message and restart the app.
If I open my app, it is updated correctly, so my update code is working, but I need that the restart app.

The Android API version is 29.

### CODE

The code below is the responsible to create the session and commited:

```
fun sessionCommit() {
    var session: Session? = null
    val params = PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL)
    val sessionId = installer.createSession(params)
    session = installer.openSession(sessionId)
    addApkToInstallSession(
        session,
        packageName,
        File(this.context.filesDir, this.apkName)
    )
    session.commit(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        this.context,
        PENDING_INTENT_INSTALL,
        Intent(this.context, AppUpdaterReceiver::class.java),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    ).intentSender);
}
```

And this is my broadcast code that work, because I receive the **PackageInstaller.STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION** correctly.

```
class AppUpdaterReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            val extras = intent.extras;
            if (extras != null) {
                val status = extras.getInt(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS);
                val message = extras.getString(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS_MESSAGE);
                when (status) {
                    PackageInstaller.STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION -> {
                        val confirmIntent = extras.get(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT) as Intent;
                        context.startActivity(confirmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                    }
                    PackageInstaller.STATUS_SUCCESS -> {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            "Atualização concluída com sucesso!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show();
                    }
                    PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE,
                    PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_ABORTED,
                    PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_BLOCKED,
                    PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_CONFLICT,
                    PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_INCOMPATIBLE,
                    PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_INVALID,
                    PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_STORAGE -> {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            "Atualização falhou! $status, $message",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show();
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            "A atualização retornou um status desconhecido: $status",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I googled about this situation many, many times, but I can't set the allow the **PackageInstalledReceiver** receive the action about the app install.

**I need that the restart app.**

Sorry with I forget some information or put something of my code in another language, but it's my firts topic in English.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).